# Trying to figure out when queries in Entity Framework are executed

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, iqueryable

This is my first time working with Entity Framework (EF) and I'm trying to learn what exactly executes a query on my database and what doesn't.

This is the code I'm working with. Don't mind the functionality, it isn't important for this question.

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    //Check if any reviews have been given.
    if (combinedReviews.Any())
    {
        var restaurantsReviewedIds = combinedReviews.Select(rev => rev.RestaurantId);

        //(1)
        ratedRestaurants = db.Restaurants.Where(rest => restaurantsReviewedIds.Contains(rest.Id))
            .DistinctBy(rest => rest.Id)
            .ToList();
    }

    //(2)
    var restsClose = db.Restaurants.Where(rest => db.Reviews.Any(rev => rev.RestaurantId == rest.Id))
        .OrderBy(rest => rest.Location.Distance(algorithmParams.Location))
        .Take(algorithmParams.AmountOfRecommendations);

    //(3)
    tempList = ratedRestaurants.Union(restsClose).ToList();
    var tempListIds = tempList.Select(rest => rest.Id); //Temporary list.

    //(4)
    restsWithAverage = db.Reviews.Where(rev => tempListIds.Contains(rev.RestaurantId))
        .GroupBy(rev => rev.RestaurantId)
        .ToList();
}
```

I have marked each piece of code with numbers, so I'll refer to them with that. Below is what I think is what happens.

1. This executes a query since I'm calling `.ToList()` here.
2. This returns an `IQueryable`, so this won't execute a query against the database.
3. This executes the query from *(2)*.
4. This executes another query since I'm calling `.ToList()`.

How close to the truth am I? Is all of this correct? If this doesn't make sense, could you give an example what executes a query and what doesn't?

I'm sorry for asking so many questions in one question, but I thought I wouldn't need to create so many questions since all of this is about a single topic.

Comment: "Trying to figure out how Entity Framework exactly works" - how long have you got!

Comment: _"Explain for each of these fragments whether they execute a database query"_ (my interpretation of your question) is not a useful question. What if you write another piece of code, are you going to ask a new question? Instead ask the question you actually want answered.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just want to figure out when queries are executed against the database. I'm brand new to EF, so I'm not sure what happens. I don't want to execute 3 queries when I can combine them into 1. I'll word my question better.

Comment: _"when queries are executed against the database"_ - when you enumerate their results.

Comment: @CodeCaster is it really that simple? So if I'd create an `IQueryable` it won't execute the query yet?

Comment: @CodeCaster I guess so, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to execute a query you can use `AsEnumerable`.

`ToList` vs `AsEnumerable`

**`ToList`**  – converts an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>`. The advantage of using `AsEnumerable` vs. `ToList` is that `AsEnumerable` does not execute the query. `AsEnumerable` preserves deferred execution and does not build an often useless intermediate list.

On the other hand, when forced execution of a LINQ query is desired, `ToList` can be a way to do that.

You could also force execution by putting a For Each loop immediately after the query expression, but by calling ToList or ToArray you cache all the data in a single collection object.

`ToLookup` and `ToDictionary` also executing the queries.

Here you can find a list of operators and if they are executing query:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693095.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Linq query execution is different per query. I recommend reading the following page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Aye, I'll remove the second question

Comment: Your answer is not an answer, read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @CodeCaster The question is poor for SO anyway.

Comment: @ChrisBint that may be true, but that doesn't change the requirements for answers.